# How do you clarify this phrase?

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

Source:http://blogs.timesofindia.indiatimes.com/mrsfunnybones/kohinoor-and-other-british-gems/

> We eat a few more raspberry scones and switch over to discussing the great poet Rumi and Shams of Tabriz and **when I say that back home, we often refer to him as Shams Tabrizi, she retorts, ‘You Indians are obsessed with the British, want to rhyme everything with Angrezi — affected lot!’**

Meaning of bold part?

The sudden use of 'affected lot' is also not clarified?

Answer (score 1):

In the context of the article, it is just humor. The author is in a conversation with his/her British friend, who is of Pakistani origin.

In the bold text, the author is saying that 'Shams of Tabriz', the spiritual instructor of Rumi is simply referred to as 'Shams Tabrizi' back home, presumably India.

To this, the author's British friend remarks, "You Indians like everything to rhyme with '*Angrezi*'". She is commenting on how 'Tabrizi' is rhyming with 'angrezi'. *Angrezi* is a Hindi word meaning 'English'. She is saying this to imply that Indians have some sort of an obsession with the British.

Overall, this is just some light humor, which if read without the context seems dull.

Comment: why she says 'affected lot' and to whom and about what?Sorry , but that not cleared

Comment: As you can tell by the use of the em dash, the writer wants to put emphasis on the phrase in the sentence. She is saying that 'Indians' are an 'affected lot', and she is saying it to the writer. Indians are affected by the British as has been described in the remaining of the sentence.